# Java Singleton Method always nullpointer exception

Tags: java, singleton

I have a class called HtmlConnect.java.
I declare the variable log as follows:

```
public Log log = Log.getInstance();
```

The Log.java file looks like this:

```
public class Log {

    private static Log instance = null;
    private String log;

    private Log() {

    }

    public static Log getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Log();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public void appendLog(String message) {
        this.log.concat(message+"\n");       
    }


    }
```

So when I call

```
log.appendLog("TestLog");
```

I always get a nullpointer exception. Why is taht?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to `appendLog` without first have instantiate the `log`.

Comment: Use a logging framework, never try and implement logging yourself. This just leads to grief for everyone involved.

Comment: This `this.log.concat(message+"\n"); ` returns the result. Discarding the result won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler solution would be like this.

```
public enum Log {;

    private static final StringBuilder LOG = new StringBuilder();

    public static synchronized void append(String message) {
        LOG.append(message).append("\n");       
    }

    public static synchronized String getString() {
        return LOG.toString();
    }

    public static synchronized String getStringAndClear() {
        String s = LOG.toString();
        LOG.setLength(0);
        return s;
    }
}
```

which you can call with

```
Log.append("Hello");
Log.append("World");

String lines = Log.getStringAndClear();
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to initialize the `log` member field. You need to do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize the log variable inside the constructor.

```
    private Log() {
      log = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally log.appendLog("TestLog"); uses log which is String and is not initialized.

Replace

```
private String log;
```

With

```
private String log = new String();
```

Comment: Instead of `new String()` use just `""`;